# Create Firestore query dependend on collection inside document

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore db that looks like this:

```
dummy_collection:{
                  id: {
                       data: {...},
                       metaData: {
                                  date: "2020-06-15",
                                   ...
                                 },
                      },
                 },
```

I want to make a query based on the `date`-field.

I tried with:

```
db.collection("dummy_collection").where("metaData/date", "==", "2020-06-15")
```

but received:

```
ValueError: Path metaData/date not consumed, residue: /date
```

Is a query like this possible with firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested fields are addressed with a `.`, not with a `/`. So:

```
db.collection("dummy_collection").where("metaData.date", "==", "2020-06-15")
```

Also see the documentation on [updating fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), which is the only in the documentation that I know mentioned the `.` notation